# Uploading a word doc via http

Tags: php, vba, http, upload, ms-word

I thought it would be pretty handy if I could upload word documents to my website from within Word using pure VBA no plugins etc...etc...

As a starting point I would like to be upload a file in my root directory c:\reg.txt and once I've got that working I'd like my macro to save the current document somewhere and then upload that.

So far my VBA code is this:

```
Sub UploadFile()
'
' UploadFile Macro
'
'
strURL = "http://www.mywebsite.com/files/upload.php"
File = "c:\reg.txt"

Set HTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.Type = 1
    objStream.Open
    objStream.LoadFromFile (File)

    HTTP.Open "POST", strURL, False
    MsgBox "Now uploading file " & File

    HTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;"
    HTTP.send objStream.Read
    MsgBox (HTTP.responseText)
    MsgBox "Uploading complete for file " & File

End Sub
```

And my php script is this:

```
<?php

$uploaddir = '/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
echo $uploadfile;
echo "<p>";

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
  echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
   echo "Upload failed";
}

echo "</p>";
echo '<pre>';
echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);
print "</pre>";

?>
```

I am conscious that there are likely to be multiple errors on both my client side and server side code as I am trying to adapt various examples I have found but I'd be very grateful for any pointers!

Answer (score 1):

Good news - I was able to figure this out in the end and I hope this code comes in handy for someone else!  In the end I opted to write my server side code in asp as I don't really know what I'm doing with php!

```
Sub UploadFile()
'
' UploadFile Macro
'
'
Dim objStream, objHttp
Dim sUrl, sFile, sName

ActiveDocument.Save
FileName = ActiveDocument.Name
Application.Documents.Add FileName
ActiveDocument.SaveAs "c:\temp\" & FileName
ActiveDocument.Close

sFile = "c:\temp\" & ActiveDocument.Name
UUID = "xxxx"
FUID = "yyyy"
sName = Right(sFile, Len(sFile) - InStrRev(sFile, "\"))

sUrl = "http://www.mywebsite.com/test.asp?File=" & sName & "&User=Ed&UUID=" & UUID & "&FUID=" & FUID

Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Mode = 3
objStream.Type = 1
objStream.Open
objStream.LoadFromFile (sFile)

If Err = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Uploading ... please wait"
End If

Set objHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objHttp.Open "POST", sUrl, False
objHttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Length", objStream.Size
objHttp.Send objStream.Read(objStream.Size)

If Err = 0 Then
    MsgBox objHttp.responseText
Else
    MsgBox "Upload Error!" & vbCrLf & Err.Description
End If

objStream.Close
Set objStream = Nothing
Set objHttp = Nothing

End Sub
```